# SQL Injection Possibilities in my code

Tags: sql-injection, vulnerability, web

This is an sql query for a registration page. I want to know what are the possible injection queries if I use the below code in my web app registration page.

```
    $stud_reg_query = "INSERT INTO `athletics`.`STUDENT`(`roll`, `name`, `batch`, `gender`, `phone`, `email`,`EVENT_1`,`EVENT_2`,`EVENT_3`)
    VALUES ('$v_roll', '$v_name', '$v_batch', '$v_gender',
        '$v_phone', '$v_email','$v_ev1','$v_ev2','$v_ev3')";
$stud_reg = mysqli_query($conn, $stud_reg_query);
```

These values are displayed after registration in a separate page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each and every place where a user-input variable is inserted makes you subject to SQL injection. You should either use prepared statements, PDO, or escape the variables properly before appending to the original query.

As an example based on your code:

```
$v_email = "', NULL, NULL, NULL) --";
```

If I can append something like this to your query, and the SQL specific characters are not escaped, your webapp is vulnerable as I just changed the way you wanted the query to work.

Comment: Thank You for the answer can you provide me with some more example queries?

Comment: There really isn't much more to say in an answer to this question. There are endless possibilities of how one could use SQL injection in this scenario. Everything from discovering data on other registered people in this system, to wreaking havoc on your application. You don't really need to spend time pondering all the possibilities and just need to code accordingly with prepared statements. It is kind of like pondering all the injuries possible if you jump off a cliff. There is no reason to jump off the cliff, so just don't do it.  No reason not to use prepared statements in 2017.

Comment: You can test your own code with tools such as sqlmap (linux) , scawlr (HP tool for windows) and sql inject me (Firefox  plug in).